# sliding neighborhood operation PYTHON

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, scipy, signal-processing

is there a python version for https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/sliding-neighborhood-operations.html, or a way to do it efficiently?

I want to be able to fit a custom sized window say [2x2] over an image/array, and apply a custom function to the values on that window. For example, like the matlab page, it could be setting the max of the surrounding numbers, though i know a convolution can do that. Specifically, I want to apply https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/delta_e.html the delta2000 function to each pixel and its neighbors and see the results.

I have not been able to find anything.

Comment: You can use `generic_filter` from `scipy.ndimage` Example here...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54440152/2836621

Comment: very helpful, thanks! any idea how to apply a function to the middle pixel in accordance with the outside pixels?

Comment: more specifically, this doesn't seem to work with pixels that have 3 values [R,G,B]

Answer (score 0):

For discrete convolution operations which are the most common sliding neighborhood methods (to apply filters on images like gaussian, blurring, e.t.c), [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) is a good library (and for any image processing task). 
 
You should check also [Numpy](https://www.numpy.org/), which is used to operate with arrays (for instance, 2D or 3D images) and works fine with OpenCV